# mysql-cluster page cant start

Tags: php, mysql

I configured mysql cluster on my 3 Vm's :

- ubuntu 12.04 desktop with ndb_mgm node is on 192.168.1.11 and there is no mysql server installed
- and 2 ubuntu servers 12.04 with sql nodes on 192.168.1.19 and 192.168.1.20
  and now I am trying to run my webpage on ubuntu desktop:

  index.php

  `<?php 
      session_start();
      include("db-info.php");
      $link = mysql_connect ($server1, $user1, $pass1);
      if (!$link)
      { 
      $link = mysql_connect ($server2, $user2, $pass2);
      }
      if(!mysql_select_db($database)) die(mysql_error());
      ?>`

  and db-info.php

  `<?
      $server1 = "192.168.1.19";
      $user1 = "user1";
      $pass1 = "pass1";
      $server2 = "192.168.1.20";
      $user2 = "user2";
      $pass2 = "pass2";
      $database = "database";
      ?>`

  and when i try to run index.php file i give error Call to undefinied mysql_connect() it it necessary to install mysql server on ndb_mgm node?

  after apt-get install php5-mysql
  error logs

  [Wed May 29 14:25:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning: 
   mysql_connect(): Host '192.168.1.11' is not allowed to connect to this
   MySQL server in /var/www/index.php on line 5

  ```
      [Wed May 29 14:25:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Host '192.168.1.11' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /var/www/index.php on line 7

      [Wed May 29 14:25:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /var/www/index.php on line 9

      [Wed May 29 14:25:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/index.php on line 9
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL extension for PHP.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: thx but now I had another error  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock(2)

Comment: Maybe you haven't configured your MySQL instances to accept connections from hosts other than `localhost` ?